# Adding, Removing and First missing positive integer

Tags: algorithm

Given an empty list. There are three types of queries `1, 2, 3`.

Query `1 x` where `x` is a positive integer indicates adding the number `x` into the list.

Query `2 x` indicates removing `x` from the list.

Query `3` indicates printing the smallest positive integer not present in the array.

Here `x` can be from `1` upto `10^9` and number of queries upto `10^5`. For the large range of `x` I can't keep a boolean array marking visited integers. How should I approach?

Comment: Following queries *1 1, 1 1, 2 1* with a list initially empty, is *1* in the resulting list or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are too many unknowns about your data to give a definitive answer here. The approach differs a lot between at least these different cases:

1. Few values.
2. A lot of values but with large gaps.
3. A lot of values with only small gaps.
4. Almost all values.

It also depends on which ones of the mentioned operations that you will do the most.

It is less than 1 GB of data so it is possible to keep it as a bit array in memory on most machines. But if the data set is sparse (case 1 and 2 above) you might want to consider sparse arrays instead, or for very sparse sets (case 1) perhaps a binary search tree or a min-heap. The heap is probably not a good idea if you are going to use operation `2` a lot.

For case 1, 2 and 4 you might consider a [range tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree). The upside to this solution is that you can do operation `3` in logarithmic time just by going leftwards down the tree and look at the first range.

It might also be possible to page out your datastructure to disk if you are not going to do a lot of random insertions.

You might also consider speeding up the search with a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), depending on what type of datastructure you choose in the end.